# Why is my SecurityWebFilterChain not being invoked?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I just started to learn Spring's new reactive programming model and for this reason I tried to write a very basic webservice.

This is my application configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class ReactiveSpringApplication {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveSpringApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        final UserDetails admin = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN").build();
        final UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER").build();

        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(admin, user);
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().authenticated().and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpHandler httpHandler() {
        final RouterFunction<ServerResponse> routes = route(GET("/"), serverRequest ->
                ServerResponse.ok().body(just("{\"message\":\"Hello world!\"}"), String.class));

        return RouterFunctions.toHttpHandler(routes);
    }

}
```

And this are my dependencies for now:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I make a `GET` request to `http://localhost:8080/` I get a `200 OK` response wit `{"message":"Hello world!"}` inside the body. However, I would expect a `401 Unauthorized` response. The `MatcherSecurityWebFilterChain` that is built inside the `securityWebFilterChain()` method is not being  invoked and thus no security rules are enforced.

What do I have to change in order to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By declaring your own `HttpHandler`, you are taking things into your own hands.

If you wish to leverage the Spring Boot + Spring Security support, you should instead declare `RouterFunction` beans and those will be mapped automatically.

See the [Spring Framework reference documentation on that point](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn-running).